# These two codes seems equal but are different

Tags: c++

why this code

```
std::string a = read_file_name();
const char* code = a.c_str();
```

is different from

```
const char* code = read_file_name().c_str();
```

Seems equals but the result is different. The first one copy the contents of `a` to `code`, the other one doesn't. 
The method `read_file_name()` returns a string
I'm working with MSVC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second case you keep a pointer obtained from and pointing to a resource in a temporary object. Immediately after the initialization of the pointer the temporary ceases to exist. You then have a **dangling pointer**, and Undefined Behavior if you use it.

---

`std::string`'s interface can't be reduced without breaking a lot of code, so such a fix will not happen. But here is one way to avoid that problem for your own classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class My_class
{
    string value_;

public:
    friend
    static auto to_c_string( My_class const& o )
        -> char const*
    { return o.value_.c_str(); }

    explicit My_class( char const s[] ): value_{ s } {}
};

auto to_c_string( My_class const&& ) -> char const* = delete;


auto foo() -> My_class { return My_class{ "temporary" }; }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    My_class o{ "lvalue" };
    cout << to_c_string( o ) << endl;                    // OK

#ifdef TEST
    cout << to_c_string( foo() ) << endl;                // !Nyet, rvalue.
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 9):

With

```
std::string a = read_file_name();
const char* code = a.c_str();
```

you have an object `a` whose life-time extends beyond the call to `read_file_name`.

With

```
const char* code = read_file_name().c_str();
```

a *temporary* object will be created, you get a pointer to its string, and then the temporary object is destructed and leaving you with a dangling and invalid pointer.

Using the pointer from the first case is valid as long as the object `a` still lives. Using the pointer from the second case is invalid immediately and will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)